# Angular5 animation/transition on binding data change

Tags: angular

I have a very simple template binding in Angular5.

```
<div class="digitsArea">
   {{this.questionsArray[ticks - 1]}}
</div>
```

here **ticks** is set by an interval in code. I want a very simple animation / transition (e.g. color fade on value change and back to normal) whenever this value changes.

I am unable to do that as the tutorials I gone through changes something on user click /etc.

Please help.

EDIT:

```
<ng-template #testContainer>
<div id="testArea">
  <div class="testHeading">
    <h3>Addition Test</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="digitsArea" [@myAwesomeAnimation]='ticks'>
    {{this.questionsArray[ticks - 1]}}
  </div>
  <div class="userInputArea" *ngIf='this.ticks == this.questionsArray.length'>
      <div class="ui-inputgroup">
          <input type="text" pInputText placeholder="Your Answer">
          <button pButton type="button" label="Submit" (click)="displayAnswer($event)"></button>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="answerArea font-weight-bold" *ngIf='showAnswer && (this.ticks == this.questionsArray.length)'>
      <h4>Correct Answer {{answer}}</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="answerArea font-weight-bold" *ngIf='showAnswer'>
      <p-button label="Go Back" (onClick)="goBack($event)"></p-button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: show your component where you add your angular animations

Comment: Please see edit. I tried some animation coding , but not working.

Comment: I think I got it. Thanks